# Finding row in pandas df and performing a diff relative to that row location

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a database object that returns my query outputs as a pandas df.

One of my queries generates a list of dates (**df1**):

```
      data_interestDate
0  2020-07-15T00:00:00
1  2020-06-11T00:00:00
2  2020-05-14T00:00:00
3  2020-04-14T00:00:00
```

The other query returns list of values corresponding to several dates (**df2**):

```
              data_date value
0   2020-07-21T00:00:00  47.0
1   2020-07-20T00:00:00  46.0
2   2020-07-17T00:00:00  50.0
3   2020-07-16T00:00:00  46.0
4   2020-07-15T00:00:00  48.0
5   2020-07-14T00:00:00  49.0
6   2020-07-13T00:00:00  48.0
7   2020-07-10T00:00:00  49.0
8   2020-07-09T00:00:00  46.0
9   2020-07-08T00:00:00  51.0
10  2020-07-07T00:00:00  49.0
11  2020-07-06T00:00:00  53.0
```

I want to iterate through df1 and find the matching dates in df2. Once I have that, in df2 I want to take the difference between the value corresponding to that date and the value x number of rows before that.
For example, for 2020-07-15T00:00:00 in df1, I would find that date in df2 and then do something like:

```
(df2['value']-df2['value'].shift(-5)).iloc()[0]
```

which should return 3.0, and then overall output of

```
2020-07-15T00:00:00  -5  3.0
2020-06-11T00:00:00  -5  ...
2020-05-14T00:00:00  -5  ...
2020-04-14T00:00:00  -5  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself doing some formatting to get you to where you wanted your format to be, but:

Query DF 1 (df1):

```
df1.head()

data_interestDate
0   2020-07-15T00:00:00
1   2020-06-11T00:00:00
2   2020-05-14T00:00:00
3   2020-04-14T00:00:00
```

Query DF 2 (df2):

```
df2.head()

    data_date   value
0   2020-07-21T00:00:00 47.0
1   2020-07-20T00:00:00 46.0
2   2020-07-17T00:00:00 50.0
3   2020-07-16T00:00:00 46.0
4   2020-07-15T00:00:00 48.0
```

Identify your shift value:

```
shift_val = -5
```

Set your literal column (since the output you desired had it):

```
df2['shift'] = shift_val
```

Generate a df2 with a 'diff' column, giving the absolute value difference of value and value.shift(shift_value):

```
df2.loc[(df2['data_date'].isin(df1['data_interestDate'])), 'diff'] = abs(pd.to_numeric(df2['value'])-pd.to_numeric(df2['value'].shift(shift_val)))
```

Your question seems to say you want to return df2, but your examples shows a df1 return.  Here's both:

Returning df1 (as df3):

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='data_interestDate', right_on='data_date', how='left').drop(['data_date','value'], axis=1)
df3['shift'] = shift_val
```

There we do lose the shift value on the join, so it's added back (no idea on this one).
Outputs:

```
df3.head()

    data_interestDate   shift   diff
0   2020-07-15T00:00:00 -5  3.0
1   2020-06-11T00:00:00 -5  NaN
2   2020-05-14T00:00:00 -5  NaN
3   2020-04-14T00:00:00 -5  NaN
```

Returning df2 (as df3):

```
df3 = df2[df2['data_date'].isin(df1['data_interestDate'])].drop(['value'],axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```
df3.head()

data_date   shift   diff
4   2020-07-15T00:00:00 -5  3.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and correct reply. I didn't explain it properly, but your first assumption was correct (the results were to be merged with df1).